# A subview of UITableCellView is shrunk when user does swipe-to-delete gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom subviews in its cells. When a user does swipe-to-delete gesture on a cell my view is shrunk for a moment while the "Delete" button is being appeared.

As I understand it happens due to some system animation which takes place when the "Delete" button is to be appeared and my subview needs to become shorter. I set my subview's contentMode to UIViewContentModeRedraw and everything looks fine *after* animation is finished.

I looked how this works in build-in Mail application and everything is fine there.

How can I avoid this shrinking? Is it possible to change this animation to "fade out" or something? Or can I handle a moment when this animation is started to make my subview shorter right away?

**SOLUTION:**

Finally I found a solution by subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding layoutSubviews method in the following way:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIView *view = [self.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 0.2f;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [view.layer addAnimation: animation forKey:@"deletingFade"];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `layoutSubviews` method in `UITableViewCell` derived class and update positions for all your subviews accordingly to `contentView.bounds.size` of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // do what ever you need to change in your cell
    return  YES;
}
```

(OR)

You can utilize the following methods in TableViewCell:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state

You can change according to state if you are using customCell.
```